# For compiled code in an R package, how to include the install path in the object files so GDB can show source info?

Tags: r

Let's say I have an R package with some C++/Fortran code under an `src` directory. After building and installing it using `R CMD`, I want to debug a script using some of the package functions using the `R -d gdb -e 'source(<my script>)'` mechanism. However, the resulting gdb session does not know about my source files, so I have to use the `dir` command every time to point to them. Is there a way to record the install path of the source files inside of the object code during the compilation process?

I tried messing around with the `-fdebug-prefix-map` flag of gcc, without success.